# Virtual method returning enum that represents type of derived object - is it ok (in terms of design)?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual

Suppose I have an abstract base class `Base`. I want the derived classes to be processed in a different way depending on their types. I could do it like this:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void process() const = 0;
};

class DerivedOne : public Base {
public:
    virtual void process() const { std::cout << "processed one" << std::endl; }
};
```

But I'd like to move the logic of processing into separate class so that derived classes were not aware of the way they are processed. I have an idea of how to do it, but I am not sure if it is common or elegant:

```
enum Type {
    TypeOne,
    TypeTwo
};

class Base {
public:
    virtual Type type() const = 0;
};

class DerivedOne : public Base {
public:
    virtual Type type() const { return TypeOne; }
};

class DerivedTwo : public Base {
public:
    virtual Type type() const { return TypeTwo; }
};

class Processor {
    void process(const Base& b) {
        switch(b.type()) {
        case TypeOne: std::cout << "processed one" << std::endl; break;
        case TypeTwo: std::cout << "processed two" << std::endl; break;
        }
    }
};
```

So the questions are:

1) is it ok when virtual method returns some constant representing the type of derived class?

2) is such approach of using `switch` on the type of object commonly used?

3) are there any other design ideas to separate processing from the object being processed?

Comment: If you need to do this, then I'd say your design is completely broken.

Comment: His example is bad (i.e. the derived classes have no functionality), but there are legitimate use cases for this, so saying that a design is completely broken if derived objects return a type identifier is wrong.

Comment: @dauphic:  Example of such a use case?

Comment: Take a 2D game, where objects have components. There may be a component that renders a static sprite, and another that renders an animation. It doesn't make sense for an object to have both a sprite and animation rendering component, so Component may have a pure virtual Type function that returns an identifier for the component (in this case, both would return Renderer), and use it to dis-allow the addition of two conflicting components with the same purpose.

Comment: @dauphic:  So then why can't `Component` have a pure virtual `Render` method, and you just call that?

Comment: @dauphic Why would the object need two rendering components anyway?

Comment: @JohnDibling: Not all components can render. Only these two can. Another component might represent an object having health. Another component might represent the object being able to move.

Comment: @dauphic: Renderable components are typically iterated separately, and backed by a `RenderableComponent` interface that provides `render()`. You're not using polymorphism appropriately by trying to take what the language provides, remove half of it, then re-implement it in a sub-par fashion in another way.

Comment: @juanchopanza: It doesn't. The purpose of having a virtual Type is that code can be added to prevent two components that are Renderers from being added to the same object; the components could be uniquely keyed on the type.

Comment: @dauphic:  If all those components derive from `Component`, then `Component` shouldn't have the `Render()` method.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: This was just an example. You can replace rendering with different types of movement (i.e. walking vs sliding vs jumping).

Comment: @dauphic: And you can apply the same logic to those cases, too.

Comment: @dauphic You are describing what appears to be a broken design.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: What if I have 20 types of components? My Object now has 20 members, of which only two may be valid, and it's certainly harder to dynamically create objects with mixtures of components. That isn't good design.

Comment: @dauphic: No, that's certainly _not_ good design, I never suggested it, and you should never end up in that situation. Which book are you learning from?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You certainly did suggest that, in response to replacing rendering with movement.

Comment: @dauphic: I absolutely did not. Read it again. At no point did I suggest dumping function after function in to your class, that are of use for only 2 of 20 instantiations.

Comment: I have another case where I use this kind of design, and I am quite unhappy with it. My program manages objects in 3D space, and for picking it has an octree. The octree stores objects of type Pickable, and when queried with a 3D ray it returns Hit objects. Since I don't know in advance what's under the mouse, and there are different types of objects, all implementing the Pickable interface, but with quite different capabilities, I must be able to distinguish between them at runtime. So Hit has a type() method that lets me query the type of object at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

That makes no sense.

You're taking virtual dispatch, a feature deliberately created to make polymorphism work without messing up your call site or removing `ClassX` logic from actually within `ClassX` ... and trying to undo all its usefulness.

You might as well not bother with polymorphism at all, and simply store your `Type` as a member variable in a single class.

Comment: But then he wouldn't be able to send an object of any class (well, of any allowed class) into process(...) as a parameter, because process(...) would be expecting some specific class (namely, the base class Base in this example).

Comment: @Anton: Huh? Don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: @Anton OP could send a `Base` or any derived type.

Answer (score 1):

Quiz Time.

**Why do we use polymorphism?**
To provide different behavior for similar operations, where the behavior is selected at run-time.

Polymorphism is used to abstract away the implementation of an operation from the provision of that operation. All `Base` objects for example have a common set of methods.  How those methods are implemented depends on the object itself.  As a user of the object, we don't care what specific kind of object it is -- only that is is derived from `Base` and therefore has certian methods on it.  We just call the method and let the object handle how it's implemented.

**Why would we need to determine at run-time which subclass an object is derived from?**
Because only the subclass provides some operation we need.

---

Designing an interface with a pure `virtual` method that indicates the actual type of object *smells*.  It's smelly because the only reason why you would need to know the actual type of an object is because the interface doesn't provide some functionality we need, and the only thing that does provide that functionality is the object itself.  But this is counter to the point of polymorphism -- to ensure the provision of functionality while leaving the details of that functionality up to the object.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using RTTI's typeid() function rather than creating your own virtual method to return the derived type.

<humor> because you are using a built-in C++ function people will be less likely to argue with you about whether your design is broken.  If the C++ standards committee thinks you need the functionality then it's probably legit! </humor>

Comment: I know you were being humorous, but I'd consider almost any use of `typeid` to be a broken design as well -- for exactly the same reasons.